# Sencha Touch 2.3: Spinner field increment by 0.1

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am working with Sencha Touch 2 and trying to use spinner field. Here is my code segment.

```
 {
                    xtype: 'spinnerfield',
                    name: 'transfer_qty',
                    itemId: 'transfer_qty',
                    locales: {
                        label: 'stock_transfer.item_qty'
                    },
                    minValue: 0,
                    increment: 1,
                    //placeHolder: 'Please enter valid quantity',
                    required: true,
                    readOnly: false
                    //cycle: true
                }
```

I am trying to increment this field by 1 however, it increment by 0.1

Sencha Touch Version is 2.3

Anyone has any idea what's wrong with this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by setting stepValue property to 1 instead of using increment property.

```
{
                    xtype: 'spinnerfield',
                    name: 'transfer_qty',
                    itemId: 'transfer_qty',
                    locales: {
                        label: 'stock_transfer.item_qty'
                    },
                    minValue: 0,
                    stepValue: 1,
                    required: true,
                    readOnly: false
                }
```